# Java replace New Lines, Commas, and Spaces at end of String

Tags: java, regex

I am using

```
mString.replaceAll("[\n,\\s]$", "");
```

Not working, what is the correct way to remove newlines commas or spaces from the end of a string if the can appear in any order.

Comment: If by any change by `end of a string` you also mean "end of each line" you would have to make regex use multiline flag `(?m)` so `$` would represent end of line, instead of end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons your attempt

```
mString.replaceAll("[\n,\\s]$", "");
```

doesn't work.  First of all, `replaceAll` does not modify the `String` instance, because `String`s are immutable.  It returns the modified string as the result of the method.  But the above statement discards the result.  So you at least need

```
mString = mString.replaceAll(...);
```

The second reason is that the replacement method looks for the pattern in order.  If it started over at the beginning of the string after each replacement, then your expression would replace a newline, comma, or whitespace at the end of the string, then it would keep doing it until there were no more such characters at the end.  But it doesn't do things this way (and if it did, it would be way too easy to write `replaceAll` expressions that looped infinitely).  `replaceAll` works like this:  It searches for the pattern, and if it finds it, it copies all characters *before* the pattern to the result.  Then, it copies the replacement string to the result.  *Then, it resets the matcher to the character* **after** *the match*.  In your case, since the pattern match goes to the end of the input (because of the `$`), the character after the match will be the end of the string, and there can be no more matches.  Thus, the matcher would only be able to replace one character.  That's why you need to add `+` to the pattern, as in the other correct answers, like Anubhava's:

```
mString = mString.replaceAll("[,\\s]+$", "");
```

Comment: +1 for answer which explains why OP should use `mString = mString.replaceAll(...);` (immutability of String) instead of just giving solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
mString = mString.replaceAll("[\n,\\s]+$", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just take out `\n` since `\s` includes new lines also. You also need to add `+` quantifier to make it match more than 1 occurrence of whitespace or comma at end.

```
mString = mString.replaceAll("[,\\s]+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mString = mString.replaceAll("(\\n|,|\\s)+$", "");`